Convergence of $\prod_{\text{prime }p\equiv3\pmod4}^\infty\frac{p}{p+1}$
I understand that "a postive integer $n$ is representable as the sum of two squares, $n=x^2+y^2$ if and only if every prime divisor $p\equiv 3$ mod $4$ of $n$ occurs with even exponent", as mentioned in this answer, so I was wondering what is the proportion of positive integers that can be expressed as the sum of two squares.
The probability that a positive integer has a prime divisor $p\equiv3\pmod4$ with an even exponent is $$1-\frac1p+\frac1{p^2}-\frac1{p^3}+\cdots=\frac1{1+\frac1p}=\frac{p}{p+1}$$by PIE, so the probability that a positive integer can be expressed as the sum of two squares would be the product of $\frac{p}{p+1}$ for all primes $p\equiv3\pmod4$, so $$\prod_{\text{prime }p\equiv3\pmod4}^\infty\frac{p}{p+1}$$
After having a computer program list this product for all the primes $p\equiv3\pmod4$ up to $100,000$, I cannot tell if this product will converge. My question is, does this infinite product converge, and is there a special closed form for this value?

It diverges to $0$ (this is a standard convention for infinite products, to be consistent with what happens when you take their logarithms). This is a special case of Dirichlet's theorem.

See art of problem solving. One really says that it diverges to zero. Concerning your product, see this post.

A more precise version is the last chapter (of volume 2)  in Topics in Number Theory by William J. LeVeque. The count of numbers up to positive $x$   is $\frac{bx}{\sqrt{\log x}}$  asymptotically, where constant $b \approx 0.7642$
